# Recording audio in C

Tags: performance, c, linux, audio, raspberry-pi

**Please note there are newer revisions of this code, [one here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/47840/27623), and [one here for continuous audio recording](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/84536/27623).**

This is a program I wrote as a .wav audio recording library for Linux.  It was developed on a Raspberry Pi, so that may affect the dependencies required.<sup>(1)</sup>

**wav.h**

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct
{
    char RIFF_marker[4];
    uint32_t file_size;
    char filetype_header[4];
    char format_marker[4];
    uint32_t data_header_length;
    uint16_t format_type;
    uint16_t number_of_channels;
    uint32_t sample_rate;
    uint32_t bytes_per_second;
    uint16_t bytes_per_frame;
    uint16_t bits_per_sample;
} WaveHeader;

WaveHeader *genericWAVHeader(uint32_t sample_rate, uint16_t bit_depth, uint16_t channels);
WaveHeader *retrieveWAVHeader(const void *ptr);
int writeWAVHeader(int fd, WaveHeader *hdr);
int recordWAV(const char *fileName, WaveHeader *hdr, uint32_t duration);
```

Here is the main program:

```
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "wav.h"

WaveHeader *genericWAVHeader(uint32_t sample_rate, uint16_t bit_depth, uint16_t channels)
{
    WaveHeader *hdr;
    hdr = malloc(sizeof(*hdr));
    if (!hdr) return NULL;

    memcpy(&hdr->RIFF_marker, "RIFF", 4);
    memcpy(&hdr->filetype_header, "WAVE", 4);
    memcpy(&hdr->format_marker, "fmt ", 4);
    hdr->data_header_length = 16;
    hdr->format_type = 1;
    hdr->number_of_channels = channels;
    hdr->sample_rate = sample_rate;
    hdr->bytes_per_second = sample_rate * channels * bit_depth / 8;
    hdr->bytes_per_frame = channels * bit_depth / 8;
    hdr->bits_per_sample = bit_depth;

    return hdr;
}

int writeWAVHeader(int fd, WaveHeader *hdr)
{
    if (!hdr)
        return -1;

    write(fd, &hdr->RIFF_marker, 4);
    write(fd, &hdr->file_size, 4);
    write(fd, &hdr->filetype_header, 4);
    write(fd, &hdr->format_marker, 4);
    write(fd, &hdr->data_header_length, 4);
    write(fd, &hdr->format_type, 2);
    write(fd, &hdr->number_of_channels, 2);
    write(fd, &hdr->sample_rate, 4);
    write(fd, &hdr->bytes_per_second, 4);
    write(fd, &hdr->bytes_per_frame, 2);
    write(fd, &hdr->bits_per_sample, 2);
    write(fd, "data", 4);

    uint32_t data_size = hdr->file_size - 36;
    write(fd, &data_size, 4);

    return 0;
}

int recordWAV(const char *fileName, WaveHeader *hdr, uint32_t duration)
{
    int err;
    int size;
    snd_pcm_t *handle;
    snd_pcm_hw_params_t *params;
    unsigned int sampleRate = hdr->sample_rate;
    int dir;
    snd_pcm_uframes_t frames = 32;
    const char *device = "plughw:1,0"; // USB microphone
    // const char *device = "default"; // Integrated system microphone
    char *buffer;
    int filedesc;

    /* Open PCM device for recording (capture). */
    err = snd_pcm_open(&handle, device, SND_PCM_STREAM_CAPTURE, 0);
    if (err)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open PCM device: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
        return err;
    }

    /* Allocate a hardware parameters object. */
    snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&params);

    /* Fill it in with default values. */
    snd_pcm_hw_params_any(handle, params);

    /* ### Set the desired hardware parameters. ### */

    /* Interleaved mode */
    err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access(handle, params, SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED);
    if (err)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting interleaved mode: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
        snd_pcm_close(handle);
        return err;
    }
    /* Signed 16-bit little-endian format */
    if (hdr->bits_per_sample == 16) err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(handle, params, SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE);
    else err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(handle, params, SND_PCM_FORMAT_U8);
    if (err)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting format: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
        snd_pcm_close(handle);
        return err;
    }
    /* Two channels (stereo) */
    err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(handle, params, hdr->number_of_channels);
    if (err)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting channels: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
        snd_pcm_close(handle);
        return err;
    }
    /* 44100 bits/second sampling rate (CD quality) */
    sampleRate = hdr->sample_rate;
    err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near(handle, params, &sampleRate, &dir);
    if (err)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting sampling rate (%d): %s\n", sampleRate, snd_strerror(err));
        snd_pcm_close(handle);
        return err;
    }
    hdr->sample_rate = sampleRate;
    /* Set period size*/
    err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near(handle, params, &frames, &dir);
    if (err)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting period size: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
        snd_pcm_close(handle);
        return err;
    }
    /* Write the parameters to the driver */
    err = snd_pcm_hw_params(handle, params);
    if (err < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to set HW parameters: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
        snd_pcm_close(handle);
        return err;
    }

    /* Use a buffer large enough to hold one period */
    err = snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size(params, &frames, &dir);
    if (err)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error retrieving period size: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
        snd_pcm_close(handle);
        return err;
    }

    size = frames * hdr->bits_per_sample / 8 * hdr->number_of_channels; /* 2 bytes/sample, 2 channels */
    buffer = (char *) malloc(size);
    if (!buffer)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "Buffer error.\n");
        snd_pcm_close(handle);
        return -1;
    }

    err = snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_time(params, &sampleRate, &dir);
    if (err)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error retrieving period time: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
        snd_pcm_close(handle);
        free(buffer);
        return err;
    }

    uint32_t pcm_data_size = hdr->sample_rate * hdr->bytes_per_frame * (duration / 1000);
    hdr->file_size = pcm_data_size + 36;

    filedesc = open(fileName, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644);
    err = writeWAVHeader(filedesc, hdr);
    if (err)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error writing .wav header.");
        snd_pcm_close(handle);
        free(buffer);
        close(filedesc);
        return err;
    }
    int totalFrames = 0;
    for(int i = ((duration * 1000) / (hdr->sample_rate / frames)); i > 0; i--)
    {
        err = snd_pcm_readi(handle, buffer, frames);
        totalFrames += err;
        if (err == -EPIPE) fprintf(stderr, "Overrun occurred: %d\n", err);
        if (err < 0) err = snd_pcm_recover(handle, err, 0);
        // Still an error, need to exit.
        if (err < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error occured while recording: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
            snd_pcm_close(handle);
            free(buffer);
            close(filedesc);
            return err;
        }
        write(filedesc, buffer, size);
    }

    close(filedesc);
    snd_pcm_drain(handle);
    snd_pcm_close(handle);
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

<sup>(1)</sup>: Right now the program needs a USB device for input. I left a comment where the input device is declared so that it can be changed as needed.
Also, I'm not sure the program will work as intended if PulseAudio is installed.

Comment: Apparently, Rasberry Pi is little-endian by default; but can be big-endian.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A few things jump out at me immediately:

1. Use `sizeof()` whenever you need the size of something with non-dynamic allocation. In other words, all of your `write` calls on the `WaveHeader` struct members should be using `sizeof`, not hard coded sizes.
2. Allocation and initialization should be separate concerns. There's no need to have the same method that initializes a struct allocate it (unless it's an opaque pointer, or you actually care where it's allocated). There's no reason your `WaveHeader` can't be on the stack.

   - As a general rule, use automatic allocation ("the stack") first and only move to dynamic allocation when you have some compelling reason (the reason usually being size varying, too big to fit on the stack, multithreading concerns, etc).
   - Separating out initialization and allocation makes it possible for the user of the API to decide what to do with memory. Unless you *need* to make this decision for them, don't.
   - If you're feeling lazy, you can always have a `genericWavHeaderInit` and `genericWaveHeaderCreate`
3. Library code should **never** output anything. Use error codes and allow the caller to handle error reporting. What if the error should be ignored for some reason? Well, too late. You already put out an error.

   - Imagine if standard library functions output errors to `stderr`. It would be absurd :).
4. Operate on resources, not what you need to create those resources

   - `RecordWAV` should take a `snd_pcm_t` and allocate/initialize it.
   - Summarize to yourself what `RecordWAV` does. Truly go through all the steps, explaining to yourself what each chunk of code does. It does a lot more than just record a WAV.
   - As a happy side effect, it relieves your hard coded USB port. That really should come from a command line argument or a config file or something. Wanting to use different USB ports should not require a recompile.
   - Another happy side effect: your resource cleanup code doesn't have to be repeat a trillion times with every exit point (much less repetitive, but much more important: less error prone!)
5. This is fairly subjective, but I don't like your naming scheme.

   - `subjectVerb` has the nice effect of provided a "namespace" of sorts (*every* widely used C library has a standard prefix (`curl_`, `qt_`, `glib_`, `apr_`, etc).
   - A suffix technically accomplishes the same namespacing effect, but it's much, much rarer
6. Likewise, when a function's sole purpose is to operate on some object (i.e. struct) that struct should typically be the first parameter (`writeWAVHeader`).
7. If you're going to go the camelCase route (which I don't know if I would in C, but that's subjective) I would stick with strict camel casing (`writeWavHeader`). It's less visually jarring, it's easier to type, and anyone familiar with WAV will understand.

   - Same with `RIFF_marker`
8. Include your own headers first, and then other headers. If your `wav.h` had a hidden dependency on a file, it could get hidden by the source file including it. It wouldn't be until you tried to include it without including that hidden dependency that you'd get a sudden mysterious undeclared symbol error.
9. `retrieveWAVHeader` isn't defined. It also seems to be an unnecessary version of `(WaveHeader*) ptr`
10. If the return of `recordWAV` is an ALSA constant (since it's one of the error codes), you should use whatever ALSA's success constant is. I can't imagine that it wouldn't be 0, but consistency with the other possible returns would be nice.

Answer (score 13):

In C, I'd rather accept a pointer to a struct to be initialized than return newly allocated heap memory.  It's clear that the caller owns the memory.  The caller has the flexibility to pass you a pointer to a `struct` on its stack.

```
void initWAVHeader(WaveHeader *hdr, uint32_t sample_rate, uint16_t bit_depth, uint16_t channels);
```

The same goes for the rest of your functions.  I'd make `WaveHeader *` the first parameter to all of the functions to give your library a sense of design consistency.

To fill in the struct, consider keeping a global `static` prototype.  Instead of setting each field piecemeal, `memcpy()` the entire struct, then fill in the parts you need to change.

---

To write the header, you should be able to write the entire struct at once, as long as the struct is correctly packed in memory.  Putting `__attribute__((__packed__))` at the end of your `struct` declaration should ensure that GCC will not add padding between the members.

---

I take issue with this style:

```
/* Signed 16-bit little-endian format */
if (hdr->bits_per_sample == 16) err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(handle, params, SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE);
else err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(handle, params, SND_PCM_FORMAT_U8);
if (err)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error setting format: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
    snd_pcm_close(handle);
    return err;
}
```

The problems I see are:

1. The `if` line is too long for my taste.  The body should have been on a separate line.
2. Too much repetition (of the `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format()` call), and yet it's not immediately obvious what the code branches have in common.
3. In C code where you have to check the error code on every library call, I like to make it a habit to *never* call a library function outside of an `if` condition.  It's an idiom — `if (OK != (err = library_call(…))) { handle_error(); }`.

So, I'd write it this way (with an extra layer of parentheses to squelch compiler warnings about assigning inside an `if`):

```
/* Signed 16-bit little-endian format or Unsigned 8-bit? */
enum snd_pcm_format_t fmt = (hdr->bits_per_sample == 16) ?
    SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE : SND_PCM_FORMAT_U8;
if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(handle, params, fmt))) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error setting format: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
    snd_pcm_close(handle);
    return err;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Your `recordWAV` is supposed to receive a header that has been setup with
`genericWAVHeader`.  That function takes the desired sample rate and applies
it to the header.  However, within `recordWAV`, the functions that setup the
PCM handle parameters determine the real sample rate (your call to
`snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near` modifies the suggested sample rate) and so
the rate encoded in the header passed to `recordWAV` can be incorrect.

With your current arrangement there is no way to fix this.  Which brings me
to...

I think the public interface is wrong.

- The header should not be public.  The caller needs to know nothing about the
  header as it is an implementation detail of the WAV file.
- There is no reason to ask the function to open a file as well as all of the
  other things it must do.  Just pass in a file descriptor (or a `FILE*`)

So I would change the function prototype to:

```
int record_wav(int fd,
               const char *device,
               uint32_t sample_rate,
               uint16_t bit_depth,
               uint16_t channels,
               uint32_t duration);
```

The record function is much too big and the error handling is repeated much
too often.  I would prefer to see a simple function like this:

```
int record_wav(int fd, ...)
{
    snd_pcm_t *h;
    int err = open_pcm_channel(&h, ...);
    if (err) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening channel: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
        return err;
    }
    err = write_header(fd, &h, ...);
    if (!err) {
        err = write_data(fd, &h, ...);
    }
    if (err) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
    }
    snd_pcm_drain(h);
    snd_pcm_close(h);
    return err;
}
```

In this, `open_pcm_channel()` opens the channel and configures it according to
the call parameters to `record_wav`, `write_header` is the only thing to know
about the header and `write_data` is the only thing to know about obtaining
and writing data and it creates and frees the necessary buffer locally.

In `open_pcm_channel()` above, the `snd_pcm_hw_params_t *params;` is
allocated, used and and freed within that function (not that you currently
don't seem to free it).  The chain of calls to 'snd' functions can be something
like:

```
snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&params);
snd_pcm_hw_params_any(handle, params);
err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access(handle, params, SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED);
if (!err) {
    err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(handle, params, format);
}
if (!err) {
    err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(handle, params, hdr->number_of_channels);
}
if (!err) {
    err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near(handle, params, &sampleRate, &dir);
}
if (!err) {
    err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near(handle, params, &frames, &dir);
}
if (!err) {
    err = snd_pcm_hw_params(handle, params);
}
if (!err) {
    err = snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size(params, &frames, &dir);
}
if (!err) {
    err = snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_time(params, &sampleRate, &dir);
}
```

or even

```
snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&p);
snd_pcm_hw_params_any(h, p);
if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_p_set_access(h, p, SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED))
    || ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(h, p, format)))
    || ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(h, p, hdr->number_of_channels)))
    || ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near(h, p, &sampleRate, &dir)))
    || ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near(h, p, &frames, &dir)))
    || ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params(h, p)))
    || ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size(p, &frames, &dir)))
    || ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_time(p, &sampleRate, &dir)))) {
    // handle error
}
```

Note that the call to `snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_time` seems redundant and
its call parameter `sampleRate` is misnamed (function gets the time not the
rate).  Also the call to `snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size` seems redundant
because `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near` returned the size used in its
call parameter.

The WAV file format uses little-endian numbers in the header.  If you are
running on a big-endian CPU your functions will not write the header
correctly.

You have no check for errors on opening or writing the file.

Your `params` is not checked for allocation error and is not freed.

Comment: That long chain could be `err = snd_pcm_func1() || snd_pcm_func2() || snd_pcm_func_last()`

Comment: @200_success IMO that would lose the int value, and leave a boolean in err.

Comment: @200_success - not if you want the final value of `err` to equal the value returned by a failing function.  In your example `err` will hold 0 or 1.

Comment: Oh, right. I was thinking of the `||` operator in e.g. Perl or JavaScript, which gives the first truthy value.

Answer (score 5):

#### Portability

- Right now you have a pretty large dependency staring right at you on the first line.

  > ```
  > #include <alsa/asoundlib.h>
  > ```

  With that one declaration, I now know that your "library" is tailored to a specific sound architecture.  Try running your code on Windows or a Mac, and your library won't cut it.

  Instead, you may need to write a wrapper for a great library named [PortAudio](http://www.portaudio.com/). Just read the first paragraph on their website if you don't believe me in thinking that one of the best C libraries out there.

  > PortAudio is a free, cross-platform, [open-source](http://www.portaudio.com/license.html), audio I/O library. 
  >   It lets you write simple audio programs in 'C' or C++ that will
  >   compile and run on many platforms including Windows, Macintosh OS X,
  >   and Unix (OSS/ALSA). It is intended to promote the exchange of audio
  >   software between developers on different platforms. [Many applications](http://www.portaudio.com/apps.html)
  >   use PortAudio for Audio I/O.

  I think your choice is clear.  Ditch the DIY method for dealing with a ton of sound architecture API's, and create a wrapper for the PortAudio library.  You won't find yourself disappointed.
- On top of the sound architecture dependency, you then assign another dependency to a *specific device*.

  > ```
  > const char *device = "plughw:1,0"; // USB microphone
  > ```

  How is this a library?  Luckily, PortAudio also can do all of the hard work for you here as well, with the function `Pa_GetDefaultInputDevice()`.

#### Standards

- You probably shouldn't use the `write()` function anymore since they aren't standardized; instead prefer `fwrite()`.

  > **C99 & C11 §7.19**
  >
  > Many implementations of the C runtime environment, most notably the
  >   UNIX operating system, provide, aside from the standard I/O library’s
  >   `fopen`, `fclose`, `fread`, `fwrite`, and `fseek`, a set of unbuffered I/O
  >   services, `open`, `close`, `read`, `write`, and `lseek`. The C89 Committee
  >   decided not to standardize the latter set of functions.

  In addition, buffered I/O is always faster than unbuffered.  There are cases where you might want to use unbuffered, such as whenever you want to ensure that the output has been written before continuing.  But in this case you will want to use `fwrite()`.
- `fopen()`, a widely-used file I/O functions that you are using, got a facelift in C11. It now supports a new exclusive create-and-open mode (`“...x“`). The new mode behaves like `O_CREAT|O_EXCL` in POSIX and is commonly used for lock files. The `“...x”` family of modes includes the following options:

  - `wx` create text file for writing with exclusive access.
  - `wbx` create binary file for writing with exclusive access.
  - `w+x` create text file for update with exclusive access.
  - `w+bx` or `wb+x` create binary file for update with exclusive access.

  Opening a file with any of the exclusive modes above fails if the file already exists or cannot be created. Otherwise, the file is created with exclusive (non-shared) access. Additionally, a safer version of `fopen()` called `fopen_s()` is also available.  That is what I would use in your code if I were you, but I'll leave that up for you to decide and change.

#### Library Design

- Your whole library was built to write out audio to a `.wav` file, and it works. But what if I want to write out a `.wav` file the way Apple writes them? (yes, they are different from the way Windows writes them for some reason) Or what if I want a `.flac` file?  I see you have written a [`.wav` to `.flac` converter](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/38944/wave-to-flac-encoder-in-c), but converting between formats takes an unnecessary amount of time.

  As a programmer, you should always be looking for ways to make your program processes more dynamic and efficient (optimally, at the same time).  Storing the audio directly into a `.flac` file would be more efficient, for example, than converting an audio file to the specific codec.  So how can we do this?

  Enter in [libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/).  This library can read and write almost every form of audio codec you can think of.  It's more dynamic than your current implementation, and it is easier to switch between the output audio file types.

#### Syntax/Style

- You should almost always be initializing variables when you declare them.

  ```
  WaveHeader *hdr  = malloc(sizeof(*hdr));
  ```
- You switch between camelCase and snake_case.  You need to be consistent.

Comment: "This is a program I wrote as a .wav audio recording library for Linux." I don't see how most of these recommendations are useful. If you're creating a library for Linux, what's wrong with using POSIX functions (`write` etc)?

Comment: @jacwah I don't mean to be rude, but did you even read my review? I explained the problem with using `write()` in my answer quite thoroughly I think. And even if the question stated that is was written for Linux, there is no problem with making recommendations to have the library be more portable (which is how libraries should strive to be).

Comment: Sorry, I might have been the rude one. I did read the review but thought it wasn't really tailored to the question. Cross platform libraries are great - but that doesn't always have to be the goal. There's nothing wrong with the answer though, I realise that my comment must sound very harsh.