# Recording Audio Continuously in C

Tags: performance, c, audio, memory-optimization

As an ongoing little side project of mine, I've been working on recording audio in [c](/questions/tagged/c).  You can the code's progression by looking at past versions ([V1.0](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/39521/27623), [V2.0](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/47840/27623)).

I've found that my past versions were too limited.  They required a certain time frame for which they would record, and then stop.  This isn't very practical for many real-world applications, so I rewrote everything so the computer would always be listening, and only record necessary data.

Here is what I would like reviewed:

- **Memory consumption**:  Obviously a huge potential problem is lots of space being consumed in recording and saving the audio to file.  Am I wasting space at all?  Every little bit counts. *Note: file storage container must be FLAC.*
- **Speed**:  I have to be processing the data *in real time*.  I can't hang for anything or I might lose precious audio data.  Is there anywhere I could speed up processing?
- **Syntax/Styling**:  How does my code look?  What about it could make it look better?  Anything I'm doing wrong syntax-wise?

Feel free to review other stuff as well, I would just like reviews to be focused on the above.  Keep in mind I've been away from the C language for a bit now, so I may have forgotten some of the more simple things ;)

---

**main.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <portaudio.h>
#include <sndfile.h>

#define FRAMES_PER_BUFFER 1024

typedef struct
{
    uint16_t formatType;
    uint8_t numberOfChannels;
    uint32_t sampleRate;
    size_t size;
    float *recordedSamples;
} AudioData;

typedef struct
{
    float *snippet;
    size_t size;
} AudioSnippet;

AudioData initAudioData(uint32_t sampleRate, uint16_t channels, int type)
{
    AudioData data;
    data.formatType = type;
    data.numberOfChannels = channels;
    data.sampleRate = sampleRate;
    data.size = 0;
    data.recordedSamples = NULL;
    return data;
}

float avg(float *data, size_t length)
{
    float sum = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        sum += fabs(*(data + i));
    }
    return (float) sum / length;
}

long storeFLAC(AudioData *data, const char *fileName)
{

    uint8_t err = SF_ERR_NO_ERROR;
    SF_INFO sfinfo =
    {
        .channels = data->numberOfChannels,
        .samplerate = data->sampleRate,
        .format = SF_FORMAT_FLAC | SF_FORMAT_PCM_16
    };

    SNDFILE *outfile = sf_open(fileName, SFM_WRITE, &sfinfo);
    if (!outfile) return -1;

    // Write the entire buffer to the file
    long wr = sf_writef_float(outfile, data->recordedSamples, data->size / sizeof(float));
    err = data->size - wr;

    // Force write to disk and close file
    sf_write_sync(outfile);
    sf_close(outfile);
    puts("Wrote to file!!!!");
    return err;
}

int main(void)
{
    PaError err = paNoError;
    if((err = Pa_Initialize())) goto done;
    const PaDeviceInfo *info = Pa_GetDeviceInfo(Pa_GetDefaultInputDevice());
    AudioData data = initAudioData(44100, info->maxInputChannels, paFloat32);
    AudioSnippet sampleBlock =
    {
        .snippet = NULL,
        .size = FRAMES_PER_BUFFER * sizeof(float) * data.numberOfChannels
    };
    PaStream *stream = NULL;
    sampleBlock.snippet = malloc(sampleBlock.size);
    time_t talking = 0;
    time_t silence = 0;
    PaStreamParameters inputParameters =
    {
        .device = Pa_GetDefaultInputDevice(),
        .channelCount = data.numberOfChannels,
        .sampleFormat = data.formatType,
        .suggestedLatency = info->defaultHighInputLatency,
        .hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = NULL
    };

    if((err = Pa_OpenStream(&stream, &inputParameters, NULL, data.sampleRate, FRAMES_PER_BUFFER, paClipOff, NULL, NULL))) goto done;
    if((err = Pa_StartStream(stream))) goto done;
    for(int i = 0;;)
    {
        err = Pa_ReadStream(stream, sampleBlock.snippet, FRAMES_PER_BUFFER);
        if (err) goto done;
        else if(avg(sampleBlock.snippet, FRAMES_PER_BUFFER) > 0.000550) // talking
        {
            printf("You're talking! %d\n", i);
            i++;
            time(&talking);
            data.recordedSamples = realloc(data.recordedSamples, sampleBlock.size * i);
            data.size = sampleBlock.size * i;
            if (data.recordedSamples) memcpy((char*)data.recordedSamples + ((i - 1) * sampleBlock.size), sampleBlock.snippet, sampleBlock.size);
            else
            {
                free(data.recordedSamples);
                data.recordedSamples = NULL;
                data.size = 0;
            }
        }
        else //silence
        {
            double test = difftime(time(&silence), talking);
            if (test >= 1.5 && test <= 10)
            {
                char buffer[100];
                snprintf(buffer, 100, "file:%d.flac", i);
                storeFLAC(&data, buffer);
                talking = 0;
                free(data.recordedSamples);
                data.recordedSamples = NULL;
                data.size = 0;
            }
        }
    }

done:
    free(sampleBlock.snippet);
    Pa_Terminate();
    return err;
}
```

Compile with: `gcc main.c -lsndfile -lportaudio` (assuming you have those libraries installed)

Comment: I suppose I'm going to be equipped with this in the future?

Comment: @rob0t Yes, yes you are.

Comment: I'm not going to attempt an answer, but it seems like there's an awful lot of logic in your Main routine. You might want to consider extracting a few subroutines. Even if the only benefit is an easier to read Main.

Comment: @syb0rg do you have fixed your code? Would be interesting to see it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Indeed you must have been working on this project for a while, since I answered a question on SO related to one of your old versions a while back. At least some of the feedback I had is still pertinent even now.

### Code and style comments

1. > ```
   > #include <stdio.h>
   > #include <stdlib.h>
   > #include <math.h>
   > #include <string.h>
   > #include <time.h>
   > #include <portaudio.h>
   > #include <sndfile.h>
   > ```

   The problem starts already here. You make heavy use of `uint32_t` and other such types, without `#include <stdint.h>`. I assume this works because you're probably still on Mac OS X, and this would also explain why your GCC doesn't complain about C99 loop initial declarations without `-std=gnu99`.
2. As mentioned previously, you make unnecessary use of pointer arithmetic, which makes the code hard to read. I definitely prefer @nhgrif's [version of your average](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/84540/42738); I find `sum += fabs(data[i]);` eminently easier on the eye.
3. The `avg()` function has at least a few other issues. First, if you want to compute when someone is talking, I wouldn't do a straight average, even with a gimmick like `fabs()`. I'd do an RMS (Root-Mean-Square) instead and then subtract the regular average (***without*** `fabs()`) from the RMS value; this computes the audio ["power"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/41779/why-do-we-use-root-mean-square-rms-values-when-talking-about-ac-voltage) in the buffer while ignoring any DC bias (non-zero average), which your code isn't robust against. This is directly connected to the number of decibels in your sample by the same power law used to "*compand*" the input from the microphone (It could be A-law or u-law, or maybe something else).

   Second, and related; At 1024 frames and a sample rate of 44100Hz, your buffers cover a period of just 23 milliseconds; In other words, only one complete cycle of a sound with frequency 43 Hz. I don't know how low @rob0t's voice goes, but you may want to increase that amount if you will be dealing with low-frequency content. When computing the RMS and DC (average), you can only get an accurate result if you capture precisely an integer number of cycles for the frequencies of interest to you; But if your buffer spans enough cycles of all frequencies of interest to you, any inaccuracy introduced by partial cycles is drowned out by the complete ones in the average.

   Thirdly, your buffer has 1024 frames, but the accumulator is `float`. I suspect you don't care about precision much here, but you may be interested in knowing that because IEEE floating-point arithmetic isn't exactly like real math, the order in which floating-point values are added may make a small difference. In particular, if you were to add up 1024 identical values, you'll loose about 10 out of 24 bits of precision on your last accumulations. This is because the accumulator will have grown to 2^10 times the size of the accumulands, and additions into the accumulator will only use the 14 MSBs while rounding off the 10 LSBs. I'd use `double` here unless it were proven to me that `avg()` is a performance bottleneck and that vectorization has already done all it can.

   Fourthly and lastly,

   > `return (float) sum / length;`

   is entirely redundant: `sum` is already a float, and you're casting it to `float` again. If you wanted to carry out this division using floating-point math, this is already guaranteed; In C, floating-point values outrank any integer in the implicit conversions. Remember, casts don't apply to the *operation* (`/`), but to their operand (here, `sum`).
4. `storeFLAC()` has no logging in case of errors, so I have no immediate explanations as to why your code, built on Linux, succeeds only in creating zero-length files. The error code it returns is completely ignored.

   > ```
   > SNDFILE *outfile = sf_open(fileName, SFM_WRITE, &sfinfo);
   > if (!outfile) return -1;
   >
   > // Write the entire buffer to the file
   > ```

   And due to lack of braces around early `return` statements, it's harder for reviewers to add their own debugging code, because it's that much more of a chore to add braces on top of a debug `printf()`. It's nice to be considerate to your reviewers, including your future self.
5. `main()` is in sore need of refactoring, specifically extraction of a few functions for each major step. The code you wrote does not "speak" to me; I must invest some effort to understand what it does. At least it is approximately a screenful, which is in my opinion a good size for a function.
6. This is gross misuse of `goto`:

   > ```
   > int main(void)
   > {
   >   PaError err = paNoError;
   >   if((err = Pa_Initialize())) goto done;
   >   const PaDeviceInfo *info = Pa_GetDeviceInfo(Pa_GetDefaultInputDevice());
   >   AudioData data = initAudioData(44100, info->maxInputChannels, paFloat32);
   >   AudioSnippet sampleBlock =
   >   {
   >       .snippet = NULL,
   >       .size = FRAMES_PER_BUFFER * sizeof(float) * data.numberOfChannels
   >   };
   >   ...
   >
   >   done:
   >   free(sampleBlock.snippet);
   >   Pa_Terminate();
   >   return err;
   > }
   > ```

   While I do approve of `goto` for error handling, you've here committed the sin of *jumping over the initialization of local variables*, then bothering to use them. Nothing guarantees that `sampleBlock.snippet` is initialized when you attempt to `free()` it: You haven't even done `sampleBlock`'s initialization if PortAudio failed to initialize!

   This is an error you would have discovered had you used GCC's and Clang's `-Wall -Wextra` flags to ask for many, many useful diagnostics. This error was reported as

   > ```
   > portaudio.c: In function ‘main’:
   > portaudio.c:135:6: warning: ‘sampleBlock.snippet’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
   >   free(sampleBlock.snippet);
   >       ^
   > ```

   . **Note however that this warning only appears when optimizations are enabled**; This is because the analysis passes GCC requires to discover such uninitialized uses are only run at `-O1` and up. It may thus be worthwhile for you to build regularly at high optimization levels, where GCC puts more effort into analysis and can as a side-effect discover potential bugs.
7. This line:

   > ```
   > if((err = Pa_OpenStream(&stream, &inputParameters, NULL, data.sampleRate, FRAMES_PER_BUFFER, paClipOff, NULL, NULL))) goto done;
   > ```

   It's pretty obvious that if you need to scroll that far right, you have greatly exceeded my 80-column soft limit. You've also not put braces around your statement, and here a nice debug `printf` would have been helpful. I certainly want to know if my stream failed to open.

   For functions with a large number of arguments with long names, I tend to put them down one per line. Don't be afraid to spend several lines on them.
8. Congratulations on your use of `difftime()` to portably and safely determine time differences. I've learned something. However, `time_t` is commonly defined as an integer number of seconds since the Epoch. Since you will be calling `time()` around 43 times per second, many consecutive calls will give the same time, and thus a difference of `0` s, while some calls will give a difference of `1` s, despite only really being separated by `23` ms.

   Better here would have been to use a higher-resolution wall-clock timer. For this type of timing I advise `gettimeofday()`; For extreme resolutions I advise `clock_gettime()` on Linux, or the much easier-to-use and lower-overhead `mach_absolute_time()` on Mac OS X.
9. This is madness:

   > ```
   > data.recordedSamples = realloc(data.recordedSamples, sampleBlock.size * i);
   > data.size = sampleBlock.size * i;
   > if (data.recordedSamples) memcpy((char*)data.recordedSamples + ((i - 1) * sampleBlock.size), sampleBlock.snippet, sampleBlock.size);
   > else
   > {
   >   free(data.recordedSamples);
   >   data.recordedSamples = NULL;
   >   data.size = 0;
   > }
   > ```

   Firstly, one of your lines here is excessively long again. You've here used the infamous `x = realloc(x, ...)` idiom, which is awful since if `realloc()` fails, you will leak memory.

   Moreover, you're `memcpy()`'ing a new block of data into your homebrew resizable vector, on top of any `memcpy()`'s inside `realloc()`. Leaving aside the fact that every 23 ms of speech you'll potentially `realloc()` and copy *the entire array of data gathered so far*, I seriously query the need for even moving any data at all. It should be possible for you to craft yourself either a double buffer or, more generally, a circular buffer, and avoid any copying at all.

   And then on top of that, look at your conditional statement again. If `data.recordedSamples` is indeed `NULL` (and thus, you've already leaked memory by loosing your last reference to that block of memory), why are you `free()`'ing said `NULL` pointer, then setting said `NULL` pointer to `NULL` *again*? It is completely ineffectual.

### Design comments

10. There is a general lack of documentation in your code. It would be helpful to know the finer points of certain things. For instance, I can quickly take it that you only record in `float` format, since your undocumented structures use only `float*`; But what precisely is a sample, snippet or frame, according to either you or PortAudio? What's the interleaving scheme for channels, if any? What is the fundamental difference between an `AudioSnippet` and `AudioData` that compelled you to make a different structure for both of them?
11. Given that you put emphasis on not dropping any audio data at all, I advise that you make this application threaded. One thread would drive the reading of data into a circular buffer, and would perform tasks with negligible computational complexity (presumably, an RMS will take sufficiently little time as to never be the bottleneck). If this thread detects speech, it can message a worker thread to start reading this buffer at the given offset and encode it into a FLAC file. Of course, if the worker thread is too slow, eventually the reading thread will exhaust the circular buffer and will have to block, possibly dropping frames.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review!  I'm glad your stalking of me around the web has lead you [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) `;)`.

Comment: Good first answer, which should also get more upvotes since it's the most complete one.

Comment: I'm upvoting this because I saw it in passing on the "hot posts" sidebar, and it contained a ton of useful design information in general. Good stuff.

Comment: @syb0rg I came back to this answer and added a few tips to render your signal processing more robust. They're under 3., the discussion of your `avg()`.

Answer (score 15):

#### If it walks like an array and talks like an array, use it like an array.

> ```
> float avg(float *data, size_t length)
> {
>     float sum = 0;
>     for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
>     {
>         sum += fabs(*(data + i));
>     }
>     return (float) sum / length;
> }
> ```

So, `data` is an array, right?  Why don't we treat it like one and access it using subscripts?

```
float avg(float *data, size_t length)
{
    float sum = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        sum += fabs(data[i]);
    }
    return (float) sum / length;
}
```

And I don't know C well enough to say for sure, but that cast in the `return` line seems unnecessary (`sum` already is a `float`).

---

#### Don't cheat your braceless 1-line `if` statements.

> ```
> if (data.recordedSamples) memcpy((char*)data.recordedSamples + ((i - 1) * sampleBlock.size), sampleBlock.snippet, sampleBlock.size);
> ```

While I'm okay-ish with very simple one-line statements being on the same line and braceless, this one is quite ridiculuous.  This is a one line because you've cheated and inlined way too much stuff.

```
if (data.recordedSamples)
{
    size_t skipIndex = (i - 1) * sampleBlock.size;
    char *destination = (char*)data.recordedSamples + skipIndex;
    memcpy(destination, sampleBlock.snippet, sampleBlock.size);
}
```

This is better much better (though admittedly, the variable names I picked may not make sense).

---

#### It's called `main()`, not `everything()`

We've overstuff `main()`.  And that, ultimately, has lead us into the rare scenario where a `goto` is actually a pretty clean way of organizing the code within the function.

I'll say that again: this is actually a relatively clean way of using a `goto` statement.  The immediately alternative is deeply nested `if` statements which really isn't clean at all.

But there's a better approach that makes the code cleaner and has the side-effect bonus of eliminating the `goto` all together: *don't cram so much into `main()`*!

Make several more functions.  Call out to your functions.  And let your functions have early `return`s.

Functions help the reader comparmentalize chunks of your code.  You did a good job with `avg` function.  "AVG" is a common abbreviation for average.  I can guess by the function name alone what it does, and I don't have to read through the 6 simple lines of logic to figure out what it's doing.  All I have to do is just see you're calling `avg()` and I know what's going on.

So find some more ways to break up and compartmentalize your code into more digestable chunks that the read can just see the function name and get the gist of what's going on here without needing to see every single line of executable code.

Comment: Re "Why don't we treat it like one and access it using subscripts?"  Because to some of us, pointers are just as natural as subscripts, and often easier to understand?

Comment: I have to agree... though I can read *(ptr + i) easily enough, the variable name does not convey it as such, so as a code reviewer I have to go looking for its declaration and assignment to make sure... whereas buf[i] is clear on initial read.  It would be better to just do *ptr++ until ptr gets to its initial value + length.

Comment: Don't even cheat the braces on one liners.  "Every if needs a {}".  Having the braces now prevents future mistakes when changing the condition.  I also believe it helps the code stand out as a conditional.

Answer (score 11):

**Design review**

Continuous reallocation of `data.recordedSamples` doesn't sound right. It may eventually fail because you require not *just* a lot of memory, but a lot of *contiguous* memory. Consider at least reusing `data.recordedSamples` instead of freeing it. That would require just one counter (how many blocks it may currently accomodate) and reduce amount of reallocations dramatically.

It also seems that you want to keep recorded samples in a contiguous space to be able to `fwrite` them in a single call. I don't think reducing the number of write calls buys any performance. Most of the time is spent in data transfer, and it doesn't depend on number of calls. In fact, large writes make the execution profile less smooth: instead of *constantly* spending *little* time, your program *sometimes* spends *much* time. A perfect opportunity to miss an important audio event.

A standard approach to such problems is double buffering (I presume that writing the buffer is faster than recording it), along the lines of:

```
    while (keep_going) {
        read_buffer(buf1);
        swap(buf1, buf2);
        write_nonblock(buf2);
    }
```

**Code review**

- `0.000550` is a strange looking magic number. `const float talking_threshold` perhaps? In any case, the value needs some rationale.
- You record some lead-out silence. I also recommend to record some lead-in. Otherwise, you may miss the few "talking" samples in the very beginning of the event.
- `avg` is an excellent candidate for speedup. Consider hardware acceleration.
- `goto` is absolutely unwarranted.

Comment: I can't agree with `goto` being "**absolutely** unwarranted" without a recommended cleaner alternative.  I can think of a better approach, but just eliminating `goto` either ends up in quite a bit of duplication or deep nesting.

Comment: Totally agree about the reallocation not being needed, and a flipflop or circular buffer being the way to go.   The API is feeding you audio in manageable chunks. Just hand those chunks directly off to the file writer.  No need to paste them together yourself, let the filesystem do that.

Comment: @nhgrif, `goto` may be useful in certain deep nests, but in this case, it can be directly replaced with a `break` for the exact same behavior..

Comment: @AShelly What about the two `goto` statements before the `for` loop?

Comment: Refactor the first part into a StreamSetup function that returns an error,  and put a `;!err;` as the test of the for loop.

Answer (score 11):

Goto conditions are often maligned as being bad practice... and, for a reason. In almost every situation where a goto is used, it's because you are doing too much in a method. Consider your main method:

> ```
> int main(void)
> {
>     PaError err = paNoError;
>     if((err = Pa_Initialize())) goto done;
>
>     .....
>
>     AudioData data = initAudioData(44100, info->maxInputChannels, paFloat32);
>     AudioSnippet sampleBlock =
>     {
>         .snippet = NULL,
>         .size = FRAMES_PER_BUFFER * sizeof(float) * data.numberOfChannels
>     };
>     PaStream *stream = NULL;
>     sampleBlock.snippet = malloc(sampleBlock.size);
>
>
>     .....
>
>     if((err = Pa_OpenStream(&stream, &inputParameters, NULL, data.sampleRate, FRAMES_PER_BUFFER, paClipOff, NULL, NULL))) goto done;
>     if((err = Pa_StartStream(stream))) goto done;
>     for(int i = 0;;)
>     {
>         err = Pa_ReadStream(stream, sampleBlock.snippet, FRAMES_PER_BUFFER);
>         if (err) goto done;
>
>         ........
>
>     }
>
> done:
>     free(sampleBlock.snippet);
>     Pa_Terminate();
>     return err;
> }
> ```

That whole thing could be done simply, as:

```
int main(void)
{
    time_t talking = 0;
    time_t silence = 0;

    PaStream *stream = NULL;
    PaError err = setup_stream(stream);
    while (!err) {
        err = process_stream(stream);
    }
    free_stream(stream);
    return err;
}
```

Then, your various method can simply `return err;` in them if there is a problem:

```
int setup_stream(PaStream stream) {
    PaError err = paNoError;
    err = Pa_Initialize();
    if (err) {
        return err;
    }
    const PaDeviceInfo *info = Pa_GetDeviceInfo(Pa_GetDefaultInputDevice());
    AudioData data = initAudioData(44100, info->maxInputChannels, paFloat32);
    AudioSnippet sampleBlock =
    {
        .snippet = NULL,
        .size = FRAMES_PER_BUFFER * sizeof(float) * data.numberOfChannels
    };

    sampleBlock.snippet = malloc(sampleBlock.size);
    PaStreamParameters inputParameters =
    {
        .device = Pa_GetDefaultInputDevice(),
        .channelCount = data.numberOfChannels,
        .sampleFormat = data.formatType,
        .suggestedLatency = info->defaultHighInputLatency,
        .hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = NULL
    };

    err = Pa_OpenStream(&stream, &inputParameters, NULL, data.sampleRate, FRAMES_PER_BUFFER, paClipOff, NULL, NULL);
    if (err) {
        return err;
    }
    return Pa_StartStream(stream);

}
```

Even that method seems too long. The process of setting up the same data is problematic.

Also, I probably messed up on the input `stream` parameter... it needs to be a pointer type that points to the newly-created stream on successful completion...

Answer (score 10):

First, you aren't using braces around one-line `if` statements:

```
if (!outfile) return -1;
```

Failing to use braces was the cause of Apple's SSL bug, as described [here](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/02/curly-braces/).

---

Why are you doing this?

```
#define FRAMES_PER_BUFFER 1024
```

Shouldn't that be `static const int FRAMES_PER_BUFFER = 1024;`?

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1674040/2509848) discusses this.

---

As @RubberDuck mentioned in the comment, you have an awful lot of logic in `main()`.  This should probably be delegated to a separate method, or multiple methods.  `main()` shouldn't contain a bunch of logic, but should be used more like an entrance point to the program.

---

Other than these points, this is some of the cleanest, neatest code I've seen.  You used spaces around your operators and your code just generally looks neat.

Comment: Omitting the braces around the `if` block is not that bad if it's a trivial statement _on the same line_. Extra parentheses around the `if` condition suppress the compiler warning about an `=` assignment instead of an `==` equality comparison.